# Lines $DA$ and $CB$ meet at $E$, show that the radical center of the circles with diameters $AC$, $BD$, $CD$ is the orthocenter of $\triangle CED$

Tags: geometry, circles

> $ABCD$ is a quadrilateral such that the sides $DA$ and $CB$ produced intersect in $E$. Prove that the [radical center](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_center_(geometry)) of the circles by taking $AC$, $BD$ and $CD$ as diameters is the [orthocenter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altitude_(triangle)#Orthocenter) of the triangle $CED$.

I attempted by dropping perpendicular from $C$ to $DA$ and from $D$ to $CB$ 
 (see the picture below), but I do not get anything further.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

Take a look at circle with diameter CD. It meets the line $AD$ at $F$ and line $AC$ at G. Obviously:

$$\angle CFD=\angle CFA=90^\circ$$

It means that the point $F$ must also be on a circle with diameter $AC$. So circles with diameters $CD$ and $CA$ intersect at points $C$ and $F$. Consequentially, line $CF$ represent their radical axis and that axis is perpendicular to line $DE$.

In exactly the same way you can show that circles with diameter $CD$ and $BD$ intersect at points $D$ and $G\in BC$. Their radical axis $DG$ is perpendicular to line $CE$.

So you have two radical axis:

$$CF\perp DE$$

$$DG\perp CE$$

Obviously, radical axis are also heights of triangle $\triangle CDE$. Intersection of these two radical axis defines the orthocenter $H$ of triangle $\triangle CDE$.

The radical axis theorem states that the three radical axes (for each pair of circles) intersect in one point called the radical center. I won't give the proof here but you can find it on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_axis) and elsewhere.

So the third radical axis (dotted line) must also pass through point $H$.

Comment: In the problem , it was stated that DA ( & not AD) and CB produced meet at E. So please modify your solution accordingly.

Comment: @RamanujamGanitPrashikshanKe Word "produced" means that you can extend the segemnt on both sides. Lines $AD$ and $DA$ are the same. So my proof is 100% correct. If you insist on cosmetics (which is pointless, I think), just swap points $A$ and $D$, $B$ and $C$ in the picture and in the proof. Everything else remains the same.

Comment: If I swap the points D and A (& also B and C) then isn't triangle CED going to change? That is my confusion.

Comment: @RamanujamGanitPrashikshanKe I have updated the picture so that it meets your request and still did not have to change a single symbol in my proof. Please check and finally accept the answer (if satisfied, of course)